# Refactor code to return String instead of println

Tags: scala, recursion

I have this Scala code which prints out all permutations of a string:

```
  def permuteRecursively(perm: String, word: String): Unit ={
    if (word.isEmpty) println(perm + word)
    else {
      for (i <- 0 to word.length -1){
        permuteRecursively(
          perm + word.charAt(i),
          word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1, word.length)
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried to refactor it so that it would return a String rather than just print the result:

```
def permuteRecursively(perm: String, word: String): String ={
    var result: String = ""
    if (word.isEmpty) result = (perm + word)
    else {
      for (i <- 0 to word.length -1){
        permuteRecursively(
          perm + word.charAt(i),
          word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1, word.length)
        )
      }
    }
    result
  }
```

But it just returns "", likely because the variable is being reset on each recursive stack call. How can I store the state between recursive calls, without using a global variable?

Comment: If it returns all the permutations, it would not be better to return a `List[String]` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing out all the permutations and returning `Unit` (nothing useful), you now want it to return, not a `String`, but a collection of `String`s.

```
def permuteRecursively(perm: String, word: String): Seq[String] =
  if (word.isEmpty) Seq(perm + word)
  else
    word.indices.flatMap { i =>
      permuteRecursively(
        perm + word.charAt(i),
        word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1, word.length)
      )
    }
```